# Working with custom value types in metawidget

Tags: jsf, metawidget

Imagine the following form/bean:

```
public class MyForm {

    private BankAccountNumber accountNumber;

    // getter + setter
}
```

where `BankAccountNumber` is a custom value object.

When I use metawidget and jsf with an instance of this class, no input field is generated for the `accountNumber` property (only the label is shown).

The problem is that metawidget does not know the `BankAccountNumber` type and wouldn't know what kind of `UIInput` should be used.

The only solution I found so far was to annotate my property with `@UiAttribute(name = "type", value = "java.lang.String")` and to have a `javax.faces.Converter` registered for the `BankAccountNumber` class.
That way, metawidget generates an `HtmlnputText`.

Is it the best solution?

I think I could also register my own `InspectionResultProcessor` to change `BankAccountNumber` to `String` everywhere but I don't even know if mapping my custom type to `String` is the right way to do it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is to register your own `WidgetBuilder` to match on an attribute `type` of `BankAccountNumber` and return the appropriate widget. You can return `null` for every other `type`, and rely on using a `CompositeWidgetBuilder` to have the widget building process 'fall through' to a regular `HtmlWidgetBuilder` for most types.

Quite what sort of `UIInput` you return for a type of `BankAccountNumber` is up to you. But if you use a `HtmlInputText` then you'll probably need to register JSF Converters in the usual way (this bit isn't specific to Metawidget) so that JSF knows how to convert from `HtmlInputText` into a `BankAccountNumber`.

For an example of registering a custom `WidgetBuilder` (and combining it with a `CompositeWidgetBuilder`), see section 2.4.4 and 2.4.5 of the User Guide: http://metawidget.org/doc/reference/en/html/ch02s04.html